# Displaying SQL row in PHP-based webpage based on selection from drop-down menu

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi I'm trying to create a web-page that selects and displays the SQL row connected to the selected name from a drop-down menu. I've gotten everything to work except actually displaying the row when selected by the drop-down, here is some code I've cobbled together from various sources including Stack Overflow.

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       die();
     }

     //if your connection succeded
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Charities" ;
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <select name="list">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['Name']; ?>"><?= $row['Name']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="See Points">
 </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
       $(function(){
           $("select[name=list]").on("change", function () {
                 var valueSelected = $(this).val();
                 $("#value-selected").html(valueSelected);
           });
       });
  </script>
```

Currently I'm a little confused where to place the php prompt to display the information, I'm very new to PHP and SQL. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your question is somewhat inaudible... If you mean how you can get information after submitting the form. you can get value of selected dropdown by **$_POST['list']** .

Answer (score 0):

You can just add :

```
<p id="value-selected"></p>
```

You can add it between the form and the first script or before the form, or anywhere else in the html code.